# How do I get a Japanese keymap?

Tags: keyboard-layout, japanese, utf-8

I have selected the Japanese keymap in the text entry settings. But when I bring up the keymap diagram it shows only Roman characters. When I type, it is also not Hiragana, only Roman characters.

I have had this across many Ubuntu machines on many devices. I would really like to solve this problem.  I have had to revert back to English keymap because it's the same.

Do I need to activate by pressing a certain key or something? I need hiragana and Kanji.

Attached is a copy of the keymap diagram.

[image: Screen cap of Japanese keymap]

### What I have tried

- I have repeated this process for all 4 of the Japanese keymaps available in Ubuntu
- If I use the Japanese (Kana) layout it works, but only for katakana.  I don't need katakana, I need hiragana and Kanji.

Answer (score 0):

Japanese keyboard layout is the selection that the system understands how many keys are there and where are they bound to.
You should better to select one you actually using.

To type Japanese characters, first you need to install Japanese language pack. System settings >> Language Support then install fcitx for an input method and Mozc for its engine.

```
sudo apt install language-pack-ja fcitx-mozc --install-suggests
```

Then you go back to Language Support and select fcitx for Keyboard input method. (You may need to logout/login or restart at here or next step)

Open fcitx setting

1. add "Mozc" Input Method tab
2. check Use System Tray Icon on at the Appearance tab
3. choose your favourite hotkey(shortcut) between US <> JP and set at    Global Config tab (I prefer to add Super_R as Hankaku-Zenkaku)

If you see the keyboard icon next to the clock indicator. It's done in a half way, now click on the icon (or open System setting Mozc setup (i.e. Mozc setting)

There are many things to do but you can just choose first two on the general tab, first column

- Romaji, if you prefer phonic input e.g だ for typing 'd' 'a'
- Kana, if you prefer type directly Hiragana from your Japanese keyboard

This is an instruction about it, Iv think you need to be flexible to get it through sometimes I forgot important things.

Best Regards,